# Cannot invoke because "" because service is null

Tags: java, spring-boot

I've been trying to use a springboot project that can integrate with mysql and jasperreports. The idea is that the user can add whoever to the database and then print a report with all entities. The error is at viewReport() function on my controller. It says that this.userService is null

```
@Controller
public class AppController {

@Autowired
private UserRepository repo;
private UserService userService;

@GetMapping("")
public String viewHomePage() {
    return "index";
}

@GetMapping("/register")
public String showSignUpForm(Model model) {
    model.addAttribute("user", new User());
    
    return "signup_form";
}

@GetMapping("/report")
public String generateReport() {
    userService.viewReport();
    
    return "index";
}

@PostMapping("/process_register")
public String processRegistration(User user) {
    repo.save(user);
    
    return "register_success";
}
}
```

Here is my controller. The error being the userService.viewReport();

````
@Service
public class UserService {
    
    @Autowired
    private UserRepository repo;
    
    public String viewReport() {
        Log.info("Preparing the pdf report via Jasper.");
        try {
            createPdfReport(repo.findAll());
            Log.info("File successfully saved at given path.");
        } catch (final Exception e) {
            Log.error("Some error has occured while preparing PDF document.");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return "Done in ViewReport";
    }
    
    public void createPdfReport(final List<User> users) throws JRException {
        //Fetching .jrxml file from resources folder.
        final InputStream stream = this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("/report.jrxml");
        
        //compile report from .jrxml to .jasper
        final JasperReport report = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(stream);
        
        //Fetch users from the data source
        final JRBeanCollectionDataSource source = new JRBeanCollectionDataSource(users);
        
        //Adding the additional parameters to the pdf
        final Map<String, Object> parameters = new HashMap<>();
        parameters.put("CreatedBy", "edu.sru.Smith" );
        
        //filling report with data from database
        final JasperPrint print = JasperFillManager.fillReport(report, parameters, source);
        
        //place file in c:drive
        final String filePath = "C://CPSC-488";
        //export report to pdf file
        JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdfFile(print, filePath + "Employee_Report.pdf");
        
    }
    
} ```

That is my service class that autofills with the data from the MySQL database. I have tried adding a number of annotations and other things, but I haven't had success with anything. I'm honestly just new to this whole springboot thing and annotations overall and I have no idea where to go from here.
````

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Autowired annotation should be placed on each field that needs injection.

```
@Autowired
private UserRepository repo;

@Autowired
private UserService userService;
```

Comment: That seemed to work, but now It can't identify my fields from my JasperReport :/

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the @Autowired annotation before `private UserService userService;`.

It should be

```
@Autowired
private UserRepository repo;
@Autowired
private UserService userService;
```